# Is it mathematically possible to do a discrete choice experiment with uneven choice sets?

Tags: multinomial-distribution, choice-modeling

Hard to express what I'm trying to ask in a short title.

I have a dataset in which respondents are asked to choose a hospital at which to deliver their baby.  *However*...some respondents get to choose from among 10 hospitals, some from among 100, and some from among 3, based on where they live. The full choice set of 577 hospitals is not available to any one respondent.

Is there a way to solve for this?

I could work around it: eg, I could limit respondents to `min(choice set size)`—3, in the example above—or I could artificially construct the 577 choices for every respondent.  But I'd prefer not to do either of those.

Comment: What do you hope to learn from this experiment?

Comment: Is "experiment" the right term? Wouldn't this be some kind of observational study?

Comment: @glen_b, the term does exist. I think it was called experiment because the exposures (choices) were assigned by the researchers.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov: It's still a discrete-choice experiment, in that I want to determine the taste coefficients on characteristics of these hospitals (distance, quality, price, etc).

Comment: @Penguin I certainly am aware that the term "discrete choice experiment" exists; I only question its use in this instance, rather than its existence as a term. The question suggests that choices available to subjects were a function of where the subjects lived, not something that could be assigned to a subject by the experimenter (e.g. according to random selection under an experimental design). Isn't that -- a study where the 'treatment' (available choice set) is whatever it happens to be for each subject, not what the experimenter chooses -- exactly what an observational study is?

Comment: @glen_b, yup, on that front I agree with you. Might as well just ask an open end question.

Comment: I suppose it might perhaps be conventional to call these cases "discrete choice experiments" even when they're not actually experiments (it's not really my area, so I don't know either way) but it would be a bit odd to do so, since it rather overturns the value of the term 'experiment'. I'd have been inclined to say 'discrete choice study' here.

Comment: If distance, quality, and price are the attributes then why not create imaginary generic choice sets? People living in an area with three far away hospitals should be able to express their preference over one close by, right?

Comment: @Penguin_Knight...not sure I'm totally following. What would these imaginary choice sets look like?  Example: respondent A gets 2 real life hospitals, but respondent B gets 4 real life hospitals. What would the 2 extra hospitals in respondent A's choice set look like?

Comment: @Peng I believe (from my understanding of the question) that what was presented to subjects were the actual choices available, not imaginary ones. It might well be possible to do a different study than that, sure (and then there would be - at least to some extent - the possibility to assign treatments to subjects).

Comment: @Glen_b: To the "experiment" question: first of all, the comments aren't really getting to the meat of the question.  Second of all, it is an experiment. Let's say you live in Dallas, TX. Why in the heck would I ask you about hospitals in Spokane, OR? The Spokane respondent's choice set is limited to the options she has available to her, *even in an experiment*.... As to your other statement, yes, exactly. The hospitals offered are the actual hospitals available.

Comment: @TheChainsOfMarkov My comment was intended to deal with what I see as an an issue with the use of terminology -- in the hope of improving the question, that's what comments are really for. If I was answering the question I'd be posting something in the answer box below. I don't see how what you describe is an experiment -- do you agree that the choice set presented to subjects is NOT under the control of the researcher?

Comment: e.g. see [here](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~dnett/S401/nexpvsobs.pdf). contrast "*In an 
experiment
investigators apply 
treatments to experimental units (people, 
animals, plots of land, etc.) and then 
proceed to observe the effect of the 
treatments on the experimental units.*" with "*In an 
observational study
investigators 
observe subjects and measure variables 
of interest without assigning treatments to 
the subjects.  The treatment that each 
subject receives is determined beyond the 
control of the investigator.*"... ctd

Comment: ctd... if you don't have control of the choice sets each subject has, you don't seem to have the ability to choose which treatment goes with which subject and are instead in the situation where that assignment "*is beyond the control of the investigator*". How then is that an experiment by these (conventional) definitions? What treatment are you controlling? (Note that "[discrete choice study](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22discrete+choice+study%22)" appears to be a pretty commonly used term) ... but perhaps I'll leave this to others to sort out.

Comment: @Glen_b: as much as you think you're being helpful, you're completely derailing the discussion. I didn't come here to discuss whether me presenting hospitals to a panel of women is an "experiment" or not. I came here for a mathematical discussion.  But thanks, mate.